# ubuntu java environment path, bash: /etc/environment: permission denied?

Tags: java, ubuntu, path, permission-denied, java-home

Using UBUNTU, I installed java 8 with the following command

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

and I'm trying to set the **java environment path** as follow

```
$ cat >> /etc/environment <<EOL
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre 
EOL
```

but I get this **error message**:

```
bash: /etc/environment: permission denied
```

Comment: what about trying with `sudo` ? Try this with root privileges

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Assuming that you have already the following:

   ```
    $sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
    $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default*
   ```
2. Open `/etc/environment` file with the following command.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```

   N/B: You can replace **nano** with any other editor you like e.g **atom**
3. At the end of file, add

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
   ```

The command above alone worked for me but you can also add the command below if you want.

```
JRE_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre"
```

Remember the path used here was my java installation directory, if yours is the same then you don't need to change anything, otherwise use your path.

4. Check whether your changes persisted

   $ source /etc/environment

   $ echo $JAVA_HOME

   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 2):

Try this script, save it in a file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre -y
sudo cat >> /etc/environment <<EOL
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `sudo`

```
$ sudo cat >> /etc/environment <<EOL
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre 
EOL
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following lines to set the path variables in the `/etc/environment`

```
echo export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
echo export JRE_HOME=/path/to/jre  | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

It should work.

**Note:**

You should reboot the system for changes to take effect.

And don't forget to come here after reboot and vote +1 :)-|-<

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting

Answer (score 1):

Following is the method that worked for me -

Use bashrc to create environment variable :

1. JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java
2. JRE_HOME=/path/to/jre
3. sudo vim ~/.bashrc
4. Enter Password
5. Press I(Key) to go in the insert mode
6. Write export JAVA_HOME='/path/to/java' at the end of file
7. Write export JRE_HOME='/path/to/jre' at the end of file
8. Save and Exit (:wq)